# When editing a long question on iPad there does not seem to be a way to goto the bottom of the question

Tags: support, ipad

There does not seem to be a way to expand the text-area size or goto the bottom of question/editing boxes. It I were to edit a long post I cannot find a way to get to the bottom of it. The only text I see is that which is already visible without scrolling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you scroll with two fingers? I don't have an iPad but that usually works.

Indeed, here is a video Ben made of him scrolling the text area using two finger scroll on the iPad 2.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xfFk0BI28Yk

Comment: Two fingers pulling away from each other only make it zoom in or out, not actually do anything with the text input boxs. Dragging two fingers up or down vertically does not seem to do anything.

Comment: @Karrax: Works for me: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xfFk0BI28Yk

Comment: Wow. It works! I pulled the fingers the wrong way or just did it wrong. Thank you. I blame the fever!(Im home sick :p)